# kaptKotin directories is not marked as Generated Source Root b Idea Gradle plugin

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin, kapt

I created myself an annotation processor that generates Kotlin files via Kotlin Poet. The generated `build/generated/source/kaptKotlin/debug` is not marked as `Generated Source Directory`.

I have tried marking the generated source debug directory as `Generated Source Root`. But every time I refresh Gradle it will be unmarked.

Plus I have tried adding `IDEA plugin` in the gradle as well. But the debug directory is still not marked.

```
//build.gradle
...
apply plugin: 'idea'

idea {
module {
    sourceDirs += files('build/generated/source/kaptKotlin/debug')
    generatedSourceDirs += files('build/generated/source/kaptKotlin/debug')
    }
}
```

[image: Directory not marked]